# Display spinner until page loaded with external resources

Tags: javascript, spinner, screen, loading

I want to display a spinner while the page is loading until it is fully loaded including the external resources. The page is showing banners (ads) and it is loading these banners and ads from the ad server.

I am using the following logic as a code to display the spinner and hide it once the transition end, however I think it is not checking of all page resources loaded:

HTML

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

CSS

```
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #333333;
  transition: opacity 0.75s, visibility 0.75s;
}

.loader--hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.loader::after {
  content: "";
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 15px solid #dddddd;
  border-top-color: #009578;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: loading 0.75s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes loading {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0turn);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

JS

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");

  loader.classList.add("loader--hidden");

  loader.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
    document.body.removeChild(loader);
  });
});
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

I tried to implement this code https://codepen.io/dcode-software/pen/rNYGdeg

Comment: Could you figure out a way to know if the resources are being fetched? Then you display the loader accordingly based on that.

Comment: @Unclebigay That's the problem, however there are divs in the page where the ads should be rendered, would this help figuring out anyway?

Comment: Sounds good, you can check if the div is empty or not (empty is loading, not empty means stop loading), you can achieve this using the JavaScript childNodes, read more [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-check-if-div-is-empty#:~:text=Use%20the%20childNodes%20property%20to,then%20the%20div%20is%20empty.)

However, you have to consider what happens when the request failed and the third party element doesn't load to the div.

Comment: @Unclebigay That's really all what I wanted! Thanks a lot! I will try to dig into the process of deciding if request is success or a fail. You may write your answer so I can mark it as answer. Thanks a gain.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you find it useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go about it is to check if the `div` is empty or not (empty is loading, and not empty means stop loading).

You can achieve this using the JavaScript childNodes, read more [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-check-if-div-is-empty#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20childNodes%20property%20to,then%20the%20div%20is%20empty.) However, you have to consider what happens when the **request failed** and the third-party element doesn't load to the div.